# Unable to 'use' trait

Tags: php

I'm attempting to use traits for the first time. Only I'm unable to `use` them. Using a trait when the file the trait exists in is included results in the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\hyper\Class_HyperHeuristic.php on line 38

I'm using a slightly fancy way of requiring the file and using the traits:

```
 private function require_and_use_traits($number_of_heuristics){
     for($t=1; $t<=$number_of_heuristics; $t++ ){
        require_once __BASEPATH__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'heuristic' . $t . '.php';
        use heurisitc . $t;
     }
 }
```

Although simply manually requiring them results in the same error; the issue isn't with the loop.

Performing the following command within the loop:

```
echo __BASEPATH__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'heuristic' . $t . '.php';
```

Displays a completely valid path.

I'm using PHP 5.6.30 which supports traits. Could anyone suggest what the issue is?

Comment: What is the exact code around `Class_HyperHeuristic.php:38`? How do you know that the path is valid? Why don't you use autoloading via psr-4 and composer?

Comment: Where are you `use`ing the trait? It needs to be inside a Class

Comment: @k0pernikus line 38 is the line with use heuristic . $t . I've never come across auto-loading I'll look in to it

Comment: @ishegg the private function above is within a class

Comment: It has to be outside a function. Like a parameter definition.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)? The `use` declarations must stay inside the `class` definition, outside any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `use` the Trait inside the class, outside the methods, like a parameter definition.

I suggest you read the [traits documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) (thanks @axiac for the link)

Comment: You are very welcome. Like @k0pernikus said, you should look into Autoloading. It will make your life much easier. Good luck!